# Faster and best way to ON flashlight in android

Tags: android, performance, android-camera, flashlight

I am developing a app for 2.3.3 and above android versions in which i am giving a option of Flashlight use.

My code is :

```
public void buttonClick(View view){

Camera cam = Camera.open();
Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
cam.setParameters(p);
cam.startPreview();

flashlightSwitchImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);//to change button image
}
```

Manifest.xml permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Layout File:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bSwitchOnOff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/off"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:onClick="buttonClick"
        android:contentDescription="@string/onOffButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code is working **But problem** is **flashlight respond is slow**. It starts after 1-2 second delay, and sometimes it won't work. Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems totally fine( assuming that when you press button for flash light to switch on it is not doing any other processing than this). 
But as you said that there is a delay in flashlight response, this seems your android device issue. Try changing few setting like powersaver on/off etc. 
If you face same problem then try deploying app on some other device.

Comment: this app flashlight working very fast in my device 
[link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.surpax.ledflashlight.panel)

But my app flashlight delay by 1-2 seconds. and i am currently using only this code and button image change of on/off image.

Comment: Your other code is resulting in the delay. Try inflating resources.

Comment: I writed down all code which happen during button click please see and tell me solution what should i do

Comment: Can show me the whole button onClick method and your layout xml file ?

Comment: i added whole button click method and layout xml file please check and tell me
@gRaWEty

Comment: No ... Are you not using listener or anything for listening to button click ? Like yourButton..setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View arg0) { .......    // I want to have a look at the code here

Comment: That buttonClick method with android:onClick="buttonClick" in layout file is same as you want to see. So in buttonClick method code is there what you want. and this code is working fine just i want to speed up, so if u can then please help. there is no more code of flashlight that i can show you.
@gRaWety

Comment: Thats what I am saying, there is nothing wrong you are doing in calling your flashlight. So you have to focus on your button even launch. Now only thing I can suggest is put a toast msg before and after flashlight code ..or calculate the time between you clicked the button and the moment first line of button is read...By this you will come to know how much time it took to launch button and how much to switch on the flashlight .... just try this and let me know if what I am saying is right or not